# Out of Memory - memory optimisation

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am using this layout which seems to cause a memory issue. I re-size the buttons to exactly match the screen in Program. Introduction of an Animation of one small part of the screen seems to be enough to cause an issue. The graphics are not large so it must be the large number of buttons that is causing the issue?

Perhaps I would be best off creating one large image/button and activating options/buttons based on which co-ordinate within the image they click on.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/everything"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/page"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@drawable/clear"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text=" "
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="120sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/breakerimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="#fff000"
        android:src="@drawable/clear" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/clear" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/aa"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bb"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/cc"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dd"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ee"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ff"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gg"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/hh"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ii"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/jj"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/kk"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ll"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mm"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/nn"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/oo"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/pp"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/qq"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rr"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ss"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tt"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/uu"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/vv"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ww"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/xx"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/yy"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn26"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/zz"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/clear64"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn30"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/up"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/clear" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vii4qndafcxue4/log.txt?dl=0

Details

```
>09-21 10:31:26.590: I/dalvikvm-heap(19975): Clamp target GC heap from 132.504MB to 128.000MB
    09-21 10:31:26.590: D/dalvikvm(19975): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 3% free 126221K/129188K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
    09-21 10:31:26.630: I/dalvikvm-heap(19975): Clamp target GC heap from 138.263MB to 128.000MB
    09-21 10:31:26.630: D/dalvikvm(19975): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 128022K/130996K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
    09-21 10:31:26.630: I/dalvikvm-heap(19975): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 921616-byte allocation
    09-21 10:31:26.670: I/dalvikvm-heap(19975): Clamp target GC heap from 142.254MB to 128.000MB
    09-21 10:31:26.670: D/dalvikvm(19975): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 79K, 3% free 127943K/130996K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
    09-21 10:31:26.670: E/dalvikvm-heap(19975): Out of memory on a 921616-byte allocation.
    09-21 10:31:26.670: I/dalvikvm(19975): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
    09-21 10:31:26.670: I/dalvikvm(19975):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x418d4ea0 self=0x417c88c0
    09-21 10:31:26.670: I/dalvikvm(19975):   | sysTid=19975 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074704724
    09-21 10:31:26.670: I/dalvikvm(19975):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=264 stm=94 core=1
    09-21 10:31:26.670: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1613)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:973)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3038)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1613)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16144)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at com.kissta.abcanimals.Gamescreen$16.onClick(Gamescreen.java:390)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: I/dalvikvm(19975):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: D/skia(19975): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
    09-21 10:31:26.680: D/AndroidRuntime(19975): Shutting down VM
    09-21 10:31:26.680: W/dalvikvm(19975): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418d3da0)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975): Process: com.kissta.abcanimals, PID: 19975
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1613)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.inflate(AnimationDrawable.java:282)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:973)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:913)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3038)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1613)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16144)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at com.kissta.abcanimals.Gamescreen$16.onClick(Gamescreen.java:390)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    09-21 10:31:26.680: E/AndroidRuntime(19975):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

aa.png, bb.png, etc are only 64px by 64px, single "left" image is 240px by 240px

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: It's most probably due to your ImageButton background images. Are those images big in size? Also, It seems like way too many images on screen. Is it possible to use ListView for your layout? It will optimize image loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, maybe this is not your expected answer to optimize memory usage because you dont post any of your code ( only layout ) but this hack will increase your memory heap to max size.
Add this config `android:largeHeap="true"` to your application context in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is not causing the OOM error. Layout looks fine to me.

You are probably allocating too much memory in your game/app. Check your code to see how your bitmaps/drawables are allocated and used or post your code here for us to see.

If you want to debug how memory is allocated, follow this link: 
https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

---

- What are these drawables aa, bb, cc....  etc
- What's their size?
- In which folder did you place them?
- What device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the cause of the error are your drawables. You should try using some third party library that will handle image cacheing for you. An example will be [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). This is a very nice library for your images and is easy to use.